# Error to implement Interactive transactions using Prisma ORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, transactions, prisma

I'm trying to use Interactive transactions to perform a transaction in my database, but i've got an error by the compiler while writing the function. I even tried to copy and paste the same code that is on documentation, but got the same error

> "Argument of type '(tx: any) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PrismaPromise[]'."

[prisma Interactive transactions docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#interactive-transactions-in-preview)

```
# code that i write

static async transfer(transaction: Transcation) {

        return await client.$transaction(async (ts) => {

// There is a account model in my db, with balance and ID properties
            const sender = await ts.account.update({
                data: {
                    balance: {
                        decrement: transaction.value
                    }
                },
                where: {
                    id: transaction.debitedAccountId
                }
            })

            const recipient = await ts.account.update({
                data: {
                    balance: {
                        increment: transaction.value
                    }
                },
                where: {
                    id: transaction.creditedAccountId
                }
            })

// Those will check a conditional and throw an error if true
            validateBalanceToTransaction(sender.balance)
            validateTransactionDestination(sender.id, recipient.id)
            
            return recipient;
        })
    }
```

I added previewFeatures to my generator on schema.prisma as the docs say

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

also runned

> npx prisma generate

Comment: The error message suggests that $transaction is expecting array of promises which is the behaviour of non interactive transactions: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#sequential-prisma-client-operations

Does the error go away if you pass an array?

Comment: I've tried to do `return [recipient]` instead of `return recipient` and it didn't work out

Comment: I meant passing an array in the `$transaction` and not passing a function.

Comment: Like a sequencial operation?
I think that could work, but then I wouldn't be able to perform validations between updates, would I?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You won't be able to perform validations, I would suggest you to update to Prisma version 4.7.0 in which Interactive Transactions went into GA, let me know if you get the same error in 4.7.0 version.